UISearchBar does not appear on the navigation bar (SwiftUI) only in iOS 18
I have the UISearchBar on the navigation bar in SwiftUI view. On iOS 17 or prior, the below code works, however, on the iOS 18 beta, the search bar will not appear.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var navigateToResult = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                navigateToResult = true
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigateToResult, destination: {
                NextView(number: Int.random(in: 0...100))
            })
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    var number: Int
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    SearchBar(searchText: $text)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var searchText: String
    var onSubmit: (() -> Void)?

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISearchBar {
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.text = searchText
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        let parent: SearchBar

        init(_ parent: SearchBar) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            parent.searchText = searchText
        }

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            parent.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            parent.onSubmit?()
        }
    }
}

I found if I placed another ToolbarItem alongside as below, the search bar also appears. However, if I navigate from NextView to another view and come back to NextView, the search bar disappears again.
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
        Spacer()
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        SearchBar(searchText: $text)
    }
}

Any thought?
